# How to check if database has been updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, request

I have this react app that periodically makes a fetch request to a database to update a list.

Is there a way to do this without using a timing loop ?

**Block Diagram:**

[image: Screenshot Block Diagram]

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: You need to use WebSockets if don't want to poll your server periodically

Comment: Long polling or websockets are the answers

Comment: Okay thanks I'll look into websockets, never used it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the technologies you are using.

The first thing you need to think is when the notification is created. If it really is created after a database change, the DB may need to `trigger` an event notifying it. Some databases offers this service, like Postgres, MySQL and even Firebase Realtime Database.

Once you identified the event, the best case is when you have a bidirectional connection between client and server, when the server can emit an event to the client. It's a common approach to use it with websockets, but sometimes you just need to emit an notification, and then, using Firebase Cloud Notifications, you can skip to have a WS server to handle this.

Otherwise, the only way is with long pooling.